# BlackBerry 10 browser submits form using browser submit button when using preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, blackberry-10

As I'm working on a mobile version of our company website I ran into, what I believe is, an issue with the BlackBerry 10 browser. (I'm using the Q10, version 10.1.0.4181)

I'm using jQuery to bind to the submit event on a form to do an AJAX call, so I have a preventDefault, but it seems that BB10 seems to ignore this **when using the SUBMIT button the browser provides**.

It works fine when pressing the enter key or pressing the submit button of the form, but when I press the Submit button which is at the bottom of my browser (alongside with the previous/next buttons) it ignores the preventDefault **(and return false)** and still continues on submitting the form.

I've set up a jsfiddle which demonstrates this:
http://jsfiddle.net/e4AHZ/4/

The code I'm using to bind is:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('done!');
        return false; // as final resort, no luck =(
    });
});
```

Anyone else who had this issue? Is there a possible fix/workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this by adding **action="javascript:void(0);"** to you form (see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e4AHZ/11/).

I do not know if this is good enough but **action="javascript:void(0);"** is in fact part of a solution given [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818249/form-with-no-action-and-where-enter-does-not-reload-page).

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="some msg" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="some msg" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. We currently use the action for the AJAX call, but I can move it to something like data-action and use that instead. I tried it without action before, which didn't work, so this might be a solution. I'm going to try it out and if it works out well I'll mark this as the answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the action to "javascript:ajaxfunction();" where "ajaxfunction()" is the function you want to call to submit the form:

`$('form').attr("action","javascript:ajaxfunction();");`

This should allow you to take advantage of that submit button.