# Button onClick not working in Chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

JS code

```
function save_options() {


      var unesen_ip = document.getElementById('ip_add').value;
      var unesen_port = document.getElementById('port').value;
      localStorage.url = real_url;
      ...
    }
```

HTML code

```
<button onclick="save_options()">Save</button>
```

When I run  my script I get this error

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

How can I make it "executable"?
Thanks

Comment: When I Googled the error message you posted, it took me to a conversation here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798669/chrome-extesion-refused-to-evaluate-a-string-as-javascript-because-unsafe-eval  This hints that you can't use the inline JavaScript like you are using.

Comment: Xan is right. See the item he references and you will find your answer. Also, read the Chrome App docs carefully, where this requirement is explained, or see my book.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Chrome Content Security related issue....Visit following link detail information is given there it might solve your problem.....

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, tnx for your help guys.

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save_options, false);
```