# Submit buttons and Enter key issues

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prevent form submit if users has focus on any submit button or input type text (as in a filtering datagrid).

I'm considering 2 options

- replace submit button with some kind of `<p onclick='submitform&parameters'>Add</p>`
- block the enter key on buttons and some preferred input fields

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why? people expect the enter key to submit a form, especially when a button is focused.

are you attaching other behaviour to the buttons?

Comment: you've got a point, but i want to explicitly prevent this on some pages

Comment: the right keyword combination reveals nice links to the same question :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567644/submit-form-problem-enter-key, will reply if that helped

Comment: it did help, question closed, thanks for sharing your opinion Patricia

Comment: you should post your solution as the answer. even if it is just that that question is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
input id="txt" type="text" onKeyPress="if (event.which == 13) return false;"></input>
```

Link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567644/submit-form-problem-enter-key
```

Question closed

Answer (score 2):

If you add an `onKeyPress` event to the element in question, you can prevent the default action (form submission) by returning false from the function:

```
<input id="txt" type="text" onKeyPress="var key = event.keyCode || event.which; if (key == 13) return false;"></input>
```

Note that the `which` property of the keyboard event is deprecated, but you'll still want to check for it to support older user agents and/or Internet Exploder ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent)).

If you don't want to use inline javascript (which is not recommended), you can instead attach an event. Also, it may be better to use the `preventDefault` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault)) method of the event object, as well as the `stopPropagation` method ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation)) - the necessity for these methods this is highly dependent on what other events you have attached to the form or the elements:

```
var preventFormSubmit = function (event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (key != 13)
        return;
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    else event.cancelBubble = true; // deprecated, for older IE
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    else event.returnValue = false; // deprecated, for older IE
    return false;
};  
var target = document.getElementById('txt');
if (typeof target.addEventListener == 'function')
    target.addEventListener('keypress', preventFormSubmit, false);
else if (typeof target.attachEvent == 'function')
    target.attachEvent('onkeypress', preventFormSubmit);
```

There are other approaches to use, such as attaching a more complex `onSumit` handler to the form itself - this may be more appropriate if you're going to be doing further manipulation of the form or data before submitting (or using AJAX to submit the form data).

Comment: great explanation, but the scope of this fix was simply for IE7+, FF and Chrome, for an intranet website, this fix is satisfactory, for something more advanced, I see your point and thank you for sharing your thoughts